# Program with command line in java

Tags: java

I need to make program for school that enters 2 Strings - one of them is containg a sentence and the other contains a word. The program should search how many times the word is exsisting in the sentence. I did the program like this (the code below) and it's working, but the teacher refuse to accept it this way. She wants me to make it work with the "command line" and because I am a begginer I don't understand how this is going to work. Would love to have some help with the code...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Search{
public static void main(String args[])
    {
    String text;
    String word;
    int found=0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Sentence: ");
    text= in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Word: ");
    word=in.nextLine();
        for (int i = -1; (i = text.indexOf(word, i + 1)) != -1; ) 
        {
        found++;
        } 
    System.out.println("The word was found "+found+" times!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ask your teacher for clarification? What did they say?

Comment: String[]args is the variable you will be using

Comment: Enter the sentence in quotes ("Something like this."), and then it is one command line argument.

Answer (score 3):

what laiello says is correct!

```
String text = args[0];
String word = args[1];
```

and when executing the program you do:

```
java Search "this is the sentence containing words" "words"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep most of your code the same. Just make this simple adjustment with your string declarations:

```
String text = args[0];
String word = args[1];
```

This is assuming you are typing the sentence first followed by the word that you are searching. The `args` array in you main holds any arguments you enter when you run the program with the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what your teacher is looking for is the ability to run your program like this:

```
java -cp . Search "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." "the"
```

Your program will use the `args` array to get the values for the sentence and the word instead of the user having to type each at a prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Work with the command line here probably means the program accepts arguments from the command line at one shot. This is how you would be running the program

```
java Search "fox" "The fox jumped"
```

In this case fox is passed as args[0] and the sentence is passed as args[1]. Then the only change you would need in your code is to substitute text with args[1] and word with args[0]. Just make sure the order of passing the arguments matches with the order of handling in code.

Answer (score 0):

args is an array where you can find the strings the user entered in the command line! You can use it like a normal array.

For ex.:
With args[0] you get the first word of the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another idea to this, you don't actually need a loop for this.

```
int diff = text.replaceAll(word, "").length();
int numberOfWords = (text.length() - diff) / word.length();
System.out.println("The number of times " + word + " appears in the text is " + numberOfWords);
```

This is more efficient because there is only one `String` manipulation. Everything else is really basic arithmetic. Just something worth thinking about!

Here it is, working in an [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/cDg8pc).